# IE9 bug - form tag missing

Tags: php, html, internet-explorer-9

I have a joomla article that contain a form was createed using rsform component

http://www.kjetilhaugmo.no/videos/36-video-6

use password: 'test' to see the content

everything works as it suppose to work in all browsers but as you expected not in IE :)

the strange thing is the form works on IE8 and IE7 but not in IE9

I looked alot for the issue and found that the tag form does not appear in the generated code on IE9

I already checked the code that responsible for creating the form and every thing is perfect

```
$formLayout = '<form method="post" '.$CSSId.$CSSClass.$CSSName.$CSSAdditionalAttributes.' enctype="multipart/form-data" action="'.RSFormProHelper::htmlEscape($u).'">'.$formLayout.'</form>';
```

I'm out of solutions

any help please

Comment: It is (unless you are UA sniffing, which is usually evil) not possible that the generated source for a given browser be different from the others. Are you using `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` for anything? If so this is likely where the problem lies. If not, chances are you don't actually have a problem and you just need to clear the cache on the IE9 instance you are using to test this.

Comment: thanks Dave for your comment, can you please check the page I'm not using any condition for the form, the code are different and dont know why :)

Comment: I do not have an IE9 instance available to test, but I would be *very* surprised if I were to see any difference. Have you tried clearing the cache?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick search on the www : http://www.rsjoomla.com/support/documentation/view-article/642-my-form-wont-submit-in-internet-explorer-9.html

I looked at your code and you do have the form inside « p » tag. You can start there.